# ASP.NET MVC - Diffrent requirements than Classic MVC Project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm coming from recenelty working on ASP.NET WebForms, and other Web Development frameworks .
Lately i wanted to get into the ASP.NET MVC. I read a Pro book and have some missing link that i can't understand .

How can you use MVC when many cases doesn't fit it exactly . What do i mean ?
In WebForms for example, you want to build a page, that has all kind of elements, that has nothing to do for your 'real' model. For example, just use a page to show a small chat, or some kind of ad, and some more kind of controllers that doesn't represent a data in your DB.

In MVC as i understand, the whole concept is to build pages with specific relation to their Model, and then it everything flows from there .
So for a store (most of MVC projects examples) it fits greats, some product, cart ...

My question is, how can you use MVC when you have all kind of pages that doesn't require a specific model use ? does that lose the whole point of using ASP.NET MVC ?

Comment: The answer is no, it doesn't lose the whole point of using ASP.NET MVC. Read more about MVC, and then you realize why and how. By the way, your question is too broad. So, I'm voting for it to be closed.

Comment: A model doesn't not need to mimic your database table structure.  If you have a page that has a mix of elements, you would create a model for that mix.

Comment: Also, it would be more helpful if you could give us an example of a "page" that you think doesn't fit well into an MVC model.

Comment: I down voted this question because it's too broad.  The purpose of this form is not for teaching wide-reaching theories.  It's for solving specific problems.  Spend some time playing around with MVC, and it will become more clear.  It DOES take some time to wrap your head around. I also made the jump from Forms to MVC not too long ago. It's a different way of thinking, but you can do all that you used to be able to do in Forms.

Comment: You don't have to have a model, there's nothing wrong with creating a controller to handle views and data without a model. For instance, if you wanted chat in your application you could create a Chat method on the Home controller and then you'd put all of your client-side chat code on a View called...well "Chat.cshtml" I guess. Your view just wouldn't be typed to some model.

Comment: For you who asked for the example, my confusion came from my real project i try to convert to MVC . I have a WebForms project, which is build over an existing big DB . The View simply has a bunch of Decorated buttons on screen and a dropdown to change enviroment. Each button simply query the DB and bring up the results into a nice table, now with MVC, what would be the model here? it's just a few buttons that query the DB, to make a model with List<Object> that represent the buttons? sounds silly and mostly false . So that was my confusion, basically turn simple Form - no model to MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of what you're talking about there's child actions (MVC 5 and previous) or view components (MVC 6). For example, you can create a child action/view component that renders the chat control, and then you merely call this in your view/layout, and your view still just worries about the actual model its dealing with.

You can also utilize partials to render portions of mostly static HTML. If that chat control, for example, was just HTML/JavaScript, you could just include it in a partial and then call that in your view/layout. The main difference between a child action/view component and partial in this context is just whether or not you need to get and pass some stuff to the view server-side first. In effect, if your control needs a model of it's own, use a child action/view component, other wise, a partial can suffice.

You can also extend `HtmlHelper` to add "controls". This is useful where there's some server-side processing that needs to be done, but it doesn't require things like hitting a database, that should be handled by your controller. Think of it has kind of a midway between a child action/view component and a partial.

Finally, although the confusion is understandable, due to the tight integration between Entity Framework and MVC, the two are actually totally interchangeable. In other words your view's "model", doesn't need to be involved with a database at all. The model is just a class instance, and that can come from anywhere, be it a database, a web service, or just statically instantiated in the action.

Comment: Ah! Thanks so much Chris, that makes things a lot clearer to me. I'm going to test your suggestions! Thanks!